# .includes() is undefined IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using `.include()` in my Code This is working fine on other browsers but not working in IE.

```
if (feauture2_1_title.includes("Phase")) {

}
```

- If IE not supported any alternates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new function. [The MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) offers a polyfill (some code you may include in your own to replace the standard function in old browsers) :

```
if (!Array.prototype.includes) {
  Array.prototype.includes = function(searchElement /*, fromIndex*/ ) {
    'use strict';
    var O = Object(this);
    var len = parseInt(O.length) || 0;
    if (len === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    var n = parseInt(arguments[1]) || 0;
    var k;
    if (n >= 0) {
      k = n;
    } else {
      k = len + n;
      if (k < 0) {k = 0;}
    }
    var currentElement;
    while (k < len) {
      currentElement = O[k];
      if (searchElement === currentElement ||
         (searchElement !== searchElement && currentElement !== currentElement)) {
        return true;
      }
      k++;
    }
    return false;
  };
}
```

But most often you'll be happy enough with one of those solutions:

```
feauture2_1_title.indexOf("Phase")!==-1
```

or

```
/Phase/.test(feauture2_1_title)
```

Comment: @muhammadumarfarooqfrank You should accept the answer. I won't get any rep (it's a CW answer) but it might help other users.

Comment: Waiting for the time of delay buddy :P